# Status "Deleted" on Podcast Connect - what to do?

Tags: itunes, podcasts

I am a novice in publishing podcasts, and recently noticed the status of my podcast on iTunes' [Podcasts Connect](https://podcastsconnect.apple.com/) is set to "Deleted". Nothing has been published from my podcast since September, despite me publishing to my podcast hub. There is no info as to why and I have not been notified.

I have tried to figure out why, and what to do about it, and I can only find info that is not relevant (that the content is illegal etc, which is not the case). I have also validated the feed. The only other thing I am guessing could be the problem is that the language is set to English, whereas the podcast itself is in Norwegian.

So, two questions:

1. Could the language be the problem here? If so, how do I change it? I couldn't find info in Squarespace (my site's hosting provider) or on help in Podcast Connect.
2. How do I go about finding out why my podcast has been deleted?

I would be grateful for any tips, as I want to get the podcast back on track spreading the word on brain research for kids.

Comment: This is affecting multiple users, see [discussions.apple.com](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7550594). Also, should the question be duplicated in [AskDifferent](http://apple.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

Over at discussions.apple.com, Roger Wilmut has [this tip](https://discussions.apple.com/message/30785890#30785890):

> To contact Support go to https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/podcasts/overview and click the 'Contact Us' link at the bottom of the page.

The link is an email address for `PodcastSupport@apple.com`. The link Roger mentions doesn't work with browser-based email readers. For native apps, it populates the email with subject *Podcasts Connect Support*  and the following in the body:

> Help is on the way. What is —
>
> - Your Name:
> - Your Podcast Title:
> - The iTunes Store URL:
> - The RSS Feed URL:
> - The Apple ID Used to Submit the Podcast:
>
> Now, how can we help?
>
> While we’re reviewing, check out Podcast Connect Resources and Help
>   for more information. https://itunespartner.apple.com/podcasts/
>
> Sincerely, Apple Inc.